# Changing font style of rows in treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Is it possible to change the font style of the data in rows in treeview?

I've done it for the column headings... not sure how to do it for rows

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = Tk()


style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Calibri', 16)) # Modify the font of the body
style.configure("mystyle.Treeview.Heading", font=('Calibri', 16,'bold')) # Modify the font of the headings
style.layout("mystyle.Treeview", [('mystyle.Treeview.treearea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})])

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, style="mystyle.Treeview")
tree.pack()

tree["columns"] = ("one", "two", "three")
tree.column("one", width=150)
tree.column("two", width=150)
tree.column("three", width=150)
tree.heading("one", text="Naar")
tree.heading("two", text="Spoor")
tree.heading("three", text="Vetrektijd")
tree['show'] = 'headings'
tree.insert("", 'end', values=('aboba', 'aboba', 'aboba'))

root.mainloop()
```